# How can I `git add` on cloned git repo by SSH?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-add

I can `git add` just add new file on repo directory. but when I make directory and add new file to this directory, I cannot `git add`.

#### Note:

- I ran `git clone` for clone private repo by ssh public key

```
$ git clone git@github.com:nyusername/mygitrepo.git
```

```
$ cd mygitrepo && ls
.gitignore
README.md
requirements.txt
my_dir
```

- `my_dir`: directory that originally existed in repo
- `.gitignore` : only have one line `*.pyc`

##### case 1: add new file where existed directory path.

```
$ cd my_dir && cat <<EOF > "tmp_file.json"
{
    "foo": bar
}
EOF
```

```
$ git status
```

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        my_dir/tmp_file.json

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I can see that I can `git add my_dir/tmp_file.json`

```
$ rm tmp_file.json
$ cd .. && ls
```

```
.gitignore
README.md
requirements.txt
my_dir
```

> delete `my_dir/tmp_file.json`

##### case 2: make dir and  add new file in here.

```
$ mkdir tmp_dir && cd tmp_dir
$ cat <<EOF > "tmp_file.json"
{
    "foo": bar
}
EOF
```

run `git status`

```
$ cd .. && git status
```

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        tmp_dir/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

only I can `git add tmp_dir/`, can't  `git add tmp_dir/tmp_file.json`

what I need help:

- Why did this happen?
- How can I `git add` with make dir and file in here?

Comment: What do you mean you can't?

Comment: Consider also using `git status -uall`, so that the untracked listing never summarizes a list of files within a directory, but rather prints out each file that exists in that directory.

Answer (score 3):

Don't panic, those are just hints.

In the first instance, my_dir/ already has tracked files in it. So Git is telling you which specific files in my_dir/ are untracked.

In the second instance, tmp_dir/ is brand new. All files within are untracked. So Git is telling you everything in tmp_dir/ is untracked.

In either case, you can `git add` the whole directory (really all the files within that directory; git does not track directories) to add all the untracked and changed files within.

Comment: thank you for your answer!

What if I want to `git add` only some files but not all?



exam)

If I run git status after create files  `tmp_one.json` and `tmp_two.json`, that looks by dir unit. I want git add only `tmp_two.json`.

Comment: If you want to `git add tmp_dir/tmp_two.json`, run `git add tmp_dir/tmp_two.json`. Git doesn't have folders, at this level, it only has files: `git add tmp_dir` means "find all files in tmp_dir and git-add each one", but you can simply list out the individual files explicitly yourself. The `git status` command normally *summarizes*, but `-uall` keeps it from doing the summary, making it easier to cut-and-paste file names.